# How to append new values in a pandas dataframe and save it to a csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have made a stock trading code, mainly for paper trading...I want to save the output to a csv file. Below is my code. I can't save that to CSV file. How to fix that???

```
columns = ["Datetime","Symbol","Trade_price","Trade_type"]
trade = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns)

if buy_condition == True:
    ce_changepos(ce_df, exch, buy = True)
    tt = datetime.datetime.today() 
    tt1 = (tt.replace(microsecond=0))
    trade.Symbol = ceSymbol
    trade.Trade_price = (ce_df['sp1'].iloc[-1])
    trade.Trade_type = "CE Buy"
    trade.Datetime = str(tt1)
    trade.to_csv(path+'trade.csv', mode ="a", header =False, index=False)
    print(f"Buy order placed for {ceSymbol}")   
else:
    print(f"CE buy condition for {ceSymbol} not fulfilled")
```

Comment: Why not to use the `csv` module?

Answer (score 0):

I propose you make a dictionary object of your input data and then simply append the dictionary object to your data frame; I am pretty sure, it is the best way you append new data row to pandas data frame. For example:

```
output = pd.DataFrame()
output = output.append(dictionary, ignore_index=True)
print(output.head())
```

In your case:

```
columns = ["Datetime","Symbol","Trade_price","Trade_type"]
trade = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns)
dict = {}

if buy_condition == True:
    ce_changepos(ce_df, exch, buy = True)
    tt = datetime.datetime.today() 
    tt1 = (tt.replace(microsecond=0))
    dict["Symbol"] = ceSymbol
    dict["Trade_price"] = (ce_df['sp1'].iloc[-1])
    dict["Trade_type"] = "CE Buy"
    dict["Datetime"] = str(tt1)
    trade.append(dict, ignore_index=True)
    trade.to_csv(path+'trade.csv', mode ="a", header =False, index=False)
    print(f"Buy order placed for {ceSymbol}")   
else:
    print(f"CE buy condition for {ceSymbol} not fulfilled")
```

I hope that it helps you.

Comment: ....it's not working.

Comment: Sorry, no one can help you if you provide no details.